# How are arrays passed in C++ by reference or value or by pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a beginner trying to learn C++. Apologies if my question is not structured properly? I was working with arrays and found out that I can manipulate the values stored in an array through a function without using the `&` or pass by reference sign. I don't understand how this is possible as the lack of `&` sign means that it is passed by value and a copy is made which is manipulated.

Elsewhere, I read that arrays are passed by pointers if this is the case I didn't use any explicit dereferencing to manipulate the data. Can you please explain what is actually happening when I pass an array?

Side note: Why is it that I have to specify column size when passing a 2D array into a function?

Comment: arrays can decay to a pointer to the first element and it is that pointer that is passed by value to a function. This decay to pointer is one of the reasons to avoid raw arrays and use an appropriate container type instead (probably `std::vector`)

Comment: Arrays are passed by pointers. if you use arr[i] it is equivalent to *(arr+i) where arr is the start address of array.

Comment: ... I shouldnt be answering in a comment, but I am sure that there is a perfect duplicate, just dont find it atm

Comment: Everything in C++ is passed by value even references (it passes the value of the reference).

Answer (score 4):

C-array decays to pointer.

Some declarations are misleading too

```
void foo(const char name[42]);
```

is in fact

```
void foo(const char* name);
```

Only reference/pointer (ugly syntax :/) allow to keep size:

```
void foo(const char (&name)[42]);
void foo(const char (*name)[42]);
```

Comment: Still looks better than `void foo(const char[42]& name)`, or does it...

Comment: That's one of the reason that you should use ``std::array`` instead of ``T[]``: it's less confusing because it doesn't decay